# Showing $f=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\psi_n(x)=e^{-x^2/2}P_n(x)$ where $P_n$ is a degree $n$ polynomial with real coefficients. Assume that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2/2}P_n=0.$$ Suppose that for any $f\in L^2$, such that $$\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2/2}P_n(x)f(x)=0,$$ then how would you show that $f=0$ a.e? Any ideas/hints?

Thanks

Comment: It suffices to show $\Psi_n$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. To this end note that polynomials are dense in $L^2([a,b])$ for any bounded interval. Do you have any ideas on how to proceed from there?

Comment: It is not true that $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2/2}P_n=0,\quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.  $$

Comment: @science: That is an assumption, not an assertion by the OP.

Comment: @snarski, maybe this is a basic question, why is polynomial dense in $L^2$

Comment: Density argument does not work!

Comment: As I said it is not true! Try $n=2$.

Comment: @amathnerd The following is true: if $f\in L^2$ and for all polynomials $P_n$ the integral $\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2/2}P_n(x)f(x)=0,$ then $f=0$ a.e. Is that your question?

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk Yes and also assume that $\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2/2}P_n=0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** consider the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R,\mu)\supseteq L^2(\mathbb R),$ where $d\mu(x)=e^{-x^2/2}dx.$ Show that polynomials are dense in $L^2(\mathbb R,e^{-x^2/2}dx).$ The condition $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2/2}P_ndx=0,\ \mbox{for all polynomials }P_n,\ \deg P_n=n,\ n\geq 1$$ implies that $P_n,\ n\in\mathbb N$ span the orthogonal complement of the constant polynomial $1\in L^2(\mathbb R,\mu).$ Further, $$\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2/2}P_n(x)f(x)dx=0,\ \mbox{for all}\ n\geq 1$$ means that $f$ (or $\overline{f}$ if we work over $\mathbb C$) is orthogonal to all $P_n,$ hence $f$ is a multiple of the $1,$ i.e. $f\equiv c$  $\mu$-a.e., hence $f\equiv c$  (Lebesgue-)a.e. Since $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ we get $f=0$ a.e.